# Azure roles are cycling - WaHostBootstrapper.exe crashing, faulting module ntdll.dll

Tags: azure

This is driving me crazy: We have a Windows Azure cloud service with a ASP.NET MVC 3 project. There have been many changes lately, so we have to deploy it every few days.

Sometimes (e.g. now), we're stuck on the following deployment error:

```
Role instances recycled for a certain amount of times during an update or upgrade operation...
```

`manage.windowsazure.com` tells us that instance 0 of our Staging deployment is non-healthy:

```
Recycling (Role has encountered an error and has stopped)
```

Instance 1 however is fine, the web services on instance 1 are working, **so the cause of the error is not our code**.

We RDP'ed to the instance and examined the Application Event Log, which displays the following error multiple times:

```
Faulting application name: WaHostBootstrapper.exe, version: 6.0.6002.18488, time stamp: 0x505cf7da
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17696, time stamp: 0x4e8147f0
Exception code: 0xc0000008
Fault offset: 0x00000000000d4995
Faulting process id: 0x970
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce474976d706d2
Faulting application path: E:\base\x64\WaHostBootstrapper.exe
Faulting module path: D:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: c26d8be8-b33c-11e2-a9be-00155d3ab8c9
```

When this happens, we are

- Re-imaging the instance
- Re-booting the instance
- Deploying again
- Creating a support ticket

Some hours later, everything works again. **We didn't change anything in the deployment, it just works again, like it did before**. At the time Microsoft Support is reacting, everything is fine again, so we cannot show them the problem.

This is so ridiculous and frustrating. We're losing days of work just because of this silly error.

**Anyone else having these problems? Any ideas how we could stop that?**

Comment: What kind of extra-curricular activity do you have in your application's initialization processes? Include things like: VPN technologies (custom or Azure-based), startup scripts, OnStart code, Logging, Service activation, Dependency Injection, etc. Any of these things, if slow (DB reads/writes with locks, installing software, etc) or fidgety (waiting on flakey VPN connections), can cause this type of behavior. If your instance isn't ready in a certain amount of time (I'm unsure of the timeout), then it assumes it's unhealthy and tries again. It only tries again so many times before giving up.

Comment: The only initialization activity is the creation of an Event Source if it doesn't already exist. That should be fast. I don't think this is a timeout, because the second instance (the healthy one) doens't have these WaHostBootstrapper.exe crashes, and doesn't have any problems at all. The first instance, however, is failing consistently for several hours.

Comment: Can you reproduce these issues in the dev fabric?

Comment: No it works fine there. Please note that the second instance works fine, so the problem is not in our code. The last time we had this problem, it was also one instance that was problematic, the other one was fine too.

Comment: That's insufficient information to claim that it's not in your code. Your code could be in a race condition that doesn't always hit or many other things. This still is most likely a problem in initialization routines, whether that means code or configuration. Two things to try: 1) Remove *all* initialization and Azure bells & whistles (no VPN, no logging, no nothing) and see if it still gets stuck. 2) Deploy it in a different service (not just prod/staging under the same service) and see how it behaves.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working again. I disabled logging and similar stuff. Not yet isolated what the cause of the problem was, but at least we can deploy again.

Comment: The way it works is you can think of there being **three** main events: `Run`, `Start` (both of which you're familiar with), and a private `Initialize` (don't go searching for this name, I'm not sure what it is or exactly what the implementation underneath is but this gets you thinking along the right lines). I'm not sure if `Start` or `Init` that runs first but there is only a limited amount of time that the Azure Server Fabric will allow them to run before it determines that they're faulty and tries again. `Init` would run things like setting up Logging, VPNs, joining domains, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check following: 
1. You have latest Azure SDK and your solution is using the correct dll references. e.g. Make sure that if you have v2.0, all references use same version. If not, build afresh.
2. All references (including packages and own libraries) are enabled with "Copy Local" = True and they are included in the package bin.
3. If you are using Storage, check the connection strings and validity of keys.
4. Check whether service configuration has correct osFamily and osVersion that you are targeting.
5. If nothing helps, try [intelliTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

for such kind of issues we found http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/10/03/troubleshooting-scenario-7-role-recycling.aspx to be a good resource for debugging.